# City list is not displaying based on selection of the state name in android

Tags: java, android, spinner

Hi in the below code on selection of the state name . city names list are populating .but after selecting state name city names are displaying only last element of the city name. city names contains a list but list is not displaying as per the state name. Statenames are displaying as per my postman response but city names are not displaying .

Can any one help me where I did the mistake.

```
   if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    GetStateMasterDataModel getStateMasterDataModel = response.body();
                    final List<StateMstrModel> getStateMasterDataModels = getStateMasterDataModel.getStateMstr();
                    for (StateMstrModel stateMstrModel : getStateMasterDataModels) {
                        StateNames = stateMstrModel.getState();
                        CityNames = stateMstrModel.getCity();
                        DistrictNames = stateMstrModel.getDistric();
                        StateMstrModel stateMstrModel1 = new StateMstrModel(StateNames, CityNames, DistrictNames);
                        stateDataList.add(stateMstrModel1);
                      //  ArrayList<String> values=new ArrayList<String>();
                        hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
                        hashSet.addAll(stateNames);
                        stateNames.clear();
                        stateNames.addAll(hashSet);
                        stateNames.add(StateNames);

                        Collections.sort(stateNames, new Comparator<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                                return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
                            }
                        });
                        CityList.add(CityNames);
                        districtNames.add(DistrictNames);

                    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, stateNames);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    state.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            if(position+1>0){
                                String sp1= String.valueOf(state.getSelectedItem());
                                if(stateNames.contains(sp1)){
                                    ArrayList<String> CityList=new ArrayList<>();
                                    CityList.add(CityNames);
                                    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                            getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_item,CityList);
                                    spinnerArrayAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                    spinnerArrayAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    city.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter1);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        }
                    });
                    }
```

Postman Response:

```
{
    "Message": "State Master List",
    "Status": true,
    "StateMstr": [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "State": "Maharashtra",
            "Distric": "Mumbai City",
            "City": "Mumbai"
        }, 
        {
            "Id": "8",
            "State": "Maharashtra",
            "Distric": "Pune",
            "City": "Pune"
        },
       {
        "Id": "13",
        "State": "Maharashtra",
        "Distric": "Nagpur",
        "City": "Nagpur"
    }
}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

displaying only last element of the city name

> Because you are passing last stored city name variable in your city `ArrayAdapter`. So you need to pass list of city name

Make an arraylist to out of ur for each loop

```
ArrayList<String> CityList=new ArrayList<>();
```

and then add your city name in the list inside ur for each loop

```
CityNames = stateMstrModel.getCity();
CityList.add(CityNames);
```

Comment: can I create new arrylist

Comment: give me some suggestion

Comment: You need to add all ur city names in an arraylist after selecting state and then pass that arraylist in ur adapter

Comment: based on your suggestion I was updated my code still it is adding only last element

Comment: Please follow above updated answer I hope it will solve ur problem.

Comment: Update your code whatever you tried and also post your getStateMasterDataModels data

Comment: Please have a look still it is not working

Comment: Post your response data I want to look in which format it's coming

Comment: Posted my response data

Comment: Response data is correct you just need to follow basic how to create spinner...Please follow this link...https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spinner-in-android-using-java-with-example/

Comment: Ok Actually Based on response only I was implemented but city spinner list is  not populating